# How to properly type RXJS WebSocket in TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript, websocket, rxjs

I have a small server that Im communicating with via WebSocket, and it sends me consistent responses to I would like to type it properly. So I'm playing around with WebSockets in Angular and I have this in my service:

```
private socket$: WebSocketSubject<ResponseInterface>;
```

```
private createSocket$(): WebSocketSubject<ResponseInterface> {
  return webSocket({
      url: 'localhost:2343'
  });
}
```

And then I'm doing:

```
const toSend: PayloadInterface = {
  sendThis: true
};
this.socket$.next(toSend);
```

Well, at this stage the above won't compile with Typescript, because I'm trying to pass PayloadInterface object into the socket, which was typed with ResponseInterface.
I also have the listening:

```
public listen$(): Observable<ResponseInterface> {
   return this.socket$.asObservable();
}
```

1. My problem is that I'm not sure which type/interface should I use to declare the socket itself. Should it be ResponseInterface, because I'm then listening to it, or should it be PayloadInterface, because I want to push (`next`) to it?
2. Then, I'll still have type conflicts with either listening to it or "nexting" to it, depending on what I choose in 1.

What am I missing? `any`/`unknown` is no go.

Comment: not sure i understood you: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-jzf67z?devtoolsheight=60

Comment: @enno.void thanks, it seems you understood my problem correctly. Combining fields from two interfaces into one is interesting and something I could consider, but it's still a workaround. I wonder if there is a better way to do it. Currently I also have this: (this.socket$ as unknown as Subject<PayloadInterface>).next(value); and my socket$ is defined as WebSocketSubject<ResponseInterface>

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but a workaround that works kinda okish- was creating a new interface.

in this case, it would look like:

```
interface WS<T,K> extends WebSocketSubject<T | K> {
  next(value: K): void;
  asObservable(): Observable<T>;
}
```

then, usage would be (for OP's case):

```
private createSocket$(): WS<ResponseInterface, PayloadInterface > {
  return webSocket({
      url: 'localhost:2343'
  }) as WS<ResponseInterface, PayloadInterface>; // really annoying to need this though.
}
```

with this, both the other functions should work properly without adding anything.
A fallback of this solution is using `pipe` directly on the websocket. Personally I used pipe only on the `asObservable` output. But if `pipe` is needed direcly in the socket, you could add the big overload that the `Observable` class implements manually. It's really cumbersome though.

Answer (score -2):

Suggest you use type definitions for socket.io-client in your Angular application. Then define a service as follows:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Observer } from 'rxjs/Observer';
import { Message } from '../model/message';
import { Event } from '../model/event';

import * as socketIo from 'socket.io-client';

const SERVER_URL = 'https://yourserverhost.com';

@Injectable()
export class SocketService {
    private socket;

    public initSocket(): void {
        this.socket = socketIo(SERVER_URL);
    }

    public send(message: Message): void {
        this.socket.emit('message', message);
    }

    public onEvent(event: Event): Observable<any> {
        return new Observable<Event>(observer => {
            this.socket.on(event, () => observer.next());
        });
    }
}
```

Define an Event enum:

```
export enum Event {
    CONNECT = 'connect',
    DISCONNECT = 'disconnect'
}
Then subscribe to your service functions from your Angular component:

export class ChatComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private socketService: SocketService) { }

   ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initIoConnection();
  }

  private initIoConnection(): void {
    this.socketService.initSocket();

    this.ioConnection = this.socketService.onMessage()
      .subscribe((message: Message) => {
        this.messages.push(message);
      });


    this.socketService.onEvent(Event.CONNECT)
      .subscribe(() => {
        console.log('Connected to the server');
      });

    this.socketService.onEvent(Event.DISCONNECT)
      .subscribe(() => {
        console.log('Disconnected');
      });
  }
}
```